# How to fit a random effect for only a subset of the observations (using R)

Tags: bayesian, random-effects-model, mixed-model, hierarchical-bayesian

Say we have the following model:
$$Y_i = \alpha + u_{j(i)} + \epsilon_i$$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$, for some groups $j=1,\ldots,J$,   and
$$Y_i = \alpha + \epsilon_i$$ for $i=m+1,\ldots,n$, where $J<m<n$. Here $u_j\stackrel{iid}{\sim}N(0,\sigma_u^2)$ and, independently, $\epsilon_i\stackrel{iid}{\sim}N(0,\sigma_\epsilon^2)$.

The idea is that the $u_j$ are “random effects”, but only a subset of the observations is affected by them.

How can such a model be fit using a general-purpose package in R (such as lme, lmer)?

Comment: It looks to me that something like a random intercept to a subgroup would be achieved by having a random coefficient ("slope") on the group indicator (dummy).